# SAPUI5 - How do I implement RichTextEditor?

Tags: sapui5, rich-text-editor, sap-web-ide

Not Sure if the Documenatation is out of Date, but the standard code for creating a new richtext editor returns

```
Cannot read property 'RichTextEditor' of undefined
```

It looks like this is because there is no sap.ui.richtexteditor in the list of included resources.

```
var oRichTextEditor1 = new sap.ui.richtexteditor.RichTextEditor("myRTE1", {
    width:"100%", 
    height:"300px",
    showGroupClipboard:true,
    showGroupStructure:true,
    showGroupFont:true,
    showGroupInsert:true,
    showGroupLink:true,
    showGroupUndo:true,
    tooltip:"My RTE Tooltip"
});
```

What are my other options for a RichText/WYSIWYG editor in SAPUI5 ?

Comment: i found RTE being very bad when it comes to binding. and complex edit/display switching modes... hope it works better in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the sap.ui.define syntax to require the RichTextEditor control in your controller. As the control library is not included in the resources, it would not be readily available.

```
sap.ui.define([
  "com/sap/app/controller/BaseController",
  .
  .
  .
  "sap/ui/richtexteditor/RichTextEditor"
], function (BaseController, ........, RichTextEditor) {

onAfterRendering: function () {

        var oRichTextEditor1 = new RichTextEditor("myRTE1", {
            width:"100%", 
            height:"300px",
            showGroupClipboard:true,
            showGroupStructure:true,
            showGroupFont:true,
            showGroupInsert:true,
            showGroupLink:true,
            showGroupUndo:true,
            tooltip:"My RTE Tooltip"
        }); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen!    This works fine from the Controller, but I'm stuggling to implement this from the view..  xmlns:rte="sap.ui.richtexteditor.RichTextEditor" is not found

Comment: It should be xmlns:rte="sap.ui.richtexteditor"  & <rte:RichTextEditor> for the control

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot Stephen!